# Reduce handmade graphics for sharper look?

Tags: print-design, workflow

From hearsay I know that some designers reduce handmade graphics (hand drawn sketches, woodcut, linocut, ...) to give the graphics a "sharp" look.

I imagine that making the original 10 times the size of the final print size (e.g. A4 → playing card, 100% → 10%) — besides being uneconomical — would remove the "handmade feel".

What percentage range should one be considering for getting both a "sharper" look while retaining the "handmade feel"?

Comment: The sharpness of an illustration depends on the resolution that it's printed at and that the image file has enough detail to support it. You may want to hand draw images larger to make it easier to draw the details but in and of itself it doesn't necessarily make anything sharper.

Comment: As a general guide, "half up" (150% of the final size) used to be a sort of industry standard back before computers took over. I'm pretty sure you can still get rulers scaled in "half up" and "third off" (the inverse, so you can tell what size something that already exists will print at).

Comment: massive upsampling and downsampling both tend to get blurry. So to retain sharpness and quality, .75x-1.5x is probably the sweet spot. However Ye Olde Tyme reason for the 150%-200% size for illustration was more about scaling away the ink skips and wavy lines and was achieved by zooming or locating the camera a mathematically calculated distance away from the art during (film) capture. This is quite different than resampling.

Answer (score 1):

That is not necesary the case for all handmade things.

In some cases the contrary is a best option, for example a brushstroke, a drop of ink. You could make thoose at a smaller scale and print it at a bigger one to see the imperfections. Another case could be making the original at 100%. This is case by case basis.

Sometimes the "imperfections" you want to hide are not the texture of the strokes, but the imperfections on the proportions of the drawing, for example details on a small face, a tiny variation could make a big nose on your character.

### The resolution is diferent than the scale

One thing that defines the sharpness is not the scale. It is the scann resolution.

You can have a big engraving, but if you take a picture of that with a miniresolution camera, your print will be pixelated or smudge.

So you have 3 aspects to consider:

**1)** Make some tests on how you want the look of your **strokes**.

**2)** Define if that scale is enough for the **detail** you want.

**3)** Define the final **size** of your image.

Strokes, detail, size.

Based on thoose points, make the math to have your minimum scann resolution. If you need the tipical 300ppi you could need a 600ppi scann if you want a 1:2 image.

### Postprocessing

Another thing could be contrasting the final scann to make the edges more sharp. Again this is resolution and scale independent.

Comment: if the 600ppi is achieved "digitally" (i.e. after it has been scanned) rather than optically (i.e. by increasing the angular diameter per pixel using a lens), then always pick the optical zoom